# How to rename a Symfony 2 installation folder correctly?

Tags: symfony

I install Symfony 2.3.0-DEV this way:

```
composer self-update
git clone https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard test1
copy .\test1\app\config\parameters.yml .\test1\app\config\parameters.yml.dist
composer install
```

But, Every time I've had to rename (ie. to "test2") the project folder. My installation breaks and shows errors:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-projects\test1\web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-projects\test1\web\app_dev.php on line 19

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-projects\test1\web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-projects\test1\web\app_dev.php on line 19
```

I tried, deleting cache folders, deleting the bootstrap.cache.php file, and re-installing/updating vendors, including the autoloader, also with cache:warmup and cache:clear, changing permissions. And still nothing...

Comment: The error message (... test1\web\app_dev.php ...) you posted seems to indicate that the test1 directory is still named test1.  So what exactly did you rename?

Comment: It's renamed, the project folder from test1 to test2. But errors still show test1 in the paths... this is the problem. Sf2 doesn't update them directly...

Comment: It doesn't update the paths because the actual paths are not stored anywhere.  S2 uses __DIR__ to keep everything relative.  This part of the error message, "in C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony-projects\test1\web\app_dev.php" really indicates that the browser has opened test1\web\app_dev.php and then gotten stuck.  Are you really sure you renamed test1 to test2?  Maybe you browser is still pointing to test1 and is using it's cache?

Comment: Cleared navigation data (all, in chrome and firefox with same results) im absolutely sure that the folder is renamed. Although Sf2 uses DIR it also uses Cache... I think there should be the problem. But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: And so test1\web\app_dev.php no longer exists at all?  It's very puzzling how your browser is has managed to open a non-existent file when you have explicitly typed in test2 in the browser's url line.  Be curious to see what the solution turns out to be.  Are you possibly using a virtual host and did you restart the server after changing from test1/web to test2/web?

Comment: @Touki Is APC used in dev enviroment ? I'm calling app_dev.php, Uhm, APC Module enabled in Apache

Comment: @Cerad test1 no longer exist. Just test2/* You can try it yourself if u follow the 4 first commands above, and then rename your test1 folder.

Comment: @JesúsFlores I had a similar issue when APC was enabled by default. Just had to switch `apc_stat` to `0`

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it ! That's what I've done.

```
composer self-update
git clone https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard test1
copy .\test1\app\config\parameters.yml .\test1\app\config\parameters.yml.dist
composer install
```

- Loaded `http://localhost/symfony-projects/test1/web/app_dev.php` once.
- Closed the browser (chrome), stopped xampp (apache/mysql), and the powershell
- Deleted */app/cache/** and */app/bootstrap.php.cache file*
- Closed the IDE, Logoff my user session in Windows 8 (starting feeling paranoid)
- Renamed the folder `test1` to `test2`
- Executed `composer update` command to call *post-update-cmd* scripts to be sure that *bootstrap.php.cache* is rebuild
- Went to `http://localhost/symfony-projects/test2/web/app_dev.php`

And then works. Probably that issue was due to locked files...

@Touki Thanks, the APC thing was a good insight but not needed it ;)

Answer (score 0):

this topic is quite old but I just had the same problem. The problem was: I installed symfony2 using command:

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition myProject 2.1.x-dev
```

but I had the same fatal error. However, my solution was to go myProject directory and run command:

```
composer update
```

And that is all, project was rebuilded and file "bootstrap.php.cache" appeard :)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Next time, just restart your machine.